# Scaffolding Error: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC project in Visual Studio 2015.

.NET Framework 4.6.1

Entity Framework 6.2.0.

Whem I try to create a view to a ActionResult method the visual studio returns the error below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateNode(XNode node, XNode previous)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddNodeSkipNotify(XNode n)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Add(Object content)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XContainerExtensions.GetOrCreateElement(XContainer container, String elementName, XAttribute[] attributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileManipulator.AddOrUpdateConfigSection(XDocument config, Version entityFrameworkVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__1(XDocument c)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileProcessor.ProcessConfigFile(ProjectItem configItem, IEnumerable`1 manipulators)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__0(ProjectItem i)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.ConfigFileFinder.FindConfigFiles(ProjectItems items, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ConnectionFactoryConfig.InitializeEntityFrameworkCommand.Execute()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

And after the error, the reference to the Entity Framework in the project desapear.

Someone has any ideia how to solve this? Or how to start to try?

Something strange too is, the nuget package manager shows the message: failed to uninstall the Entity Framework 6.1.3. But I didn't found in the project the reference for that version of the Entity.

Thanks a lot.

I tried a lot of solutions researched in the net, but no one worked.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the EF 6.2 NuGet package?

Comment: Hello Gert Arnold. Yes, I tried. But the error persisted.

Comment: Actually I created everything manually and works. The scaffolding still having the problem. I don´t know how to solve this and what could have started this.